# Should I list the sitemap index files of all the subdomains in the root domain?

Tags: xml-sitemap

I have a root domain website www.example.com and multiple subdomains - sub1.example.com, sub2.example.com, sub3.example.com.

All these subdomains have sitemap index file of their own, sub1.example.com/sitemap_index.xml, sub2.example.com/sitemap_index.xml, etc.. and it is being indexed properly.

Is it required for me to list all the sitemap index files in robots.txt of the root domain (www.example.com/robots.txt)? Or is it not mandatory?

Please explain how sitemap listing works across subdomains. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering the same thing too. According to Sitemap.org

"Note: A Sitemap index file can only specify Sitemaps that are found on the same site as the Sitemap index file. 
For example:

http://www.yoursite.com/sitemap_index.xml can include Sitemaps on http://www.yoursite.com but not on http://www.example.com or http://yourhost.yoursite.com. As with Sitemaps, your Sitemap index file must be UTF-8 encoded.​​​"